# Mutations and C++ lambdas

Tags: c++, lambda

Trying to do functional programming in C++ and getting bit by some kind of mutation rule.

I have this code:

```
  bpf_u_int32 netp, maskp;
  struct in_addr addr;
  // ...code
  auto set_address_string = [&](auto &do_assign) {
    if ((do_assign = inet_ntoa(addr)) == NULL)
      cerr << "error - inet_ntoa() failed" << endl;
    else
      cout << "Some IP: " << do_assign << endl;
  };

  char *net, *mask;
  addr.s_addr = netp;
  set_address_string(net);
  addr.s_addr = maskp;
  set_address_string(mask);
  cout << string(net) << endl;
```

Which is printing the value of mask when I expected the contents of net to be printed, say that net is supposed to be "10.0.0.0" and mask is supposed to be "255.255.255.0".

I assume this has to do with the & I used for the variable do_assign?

EDIT:

Actual output is:

```
Some IP: 10.0.0.0
Some IP: 255.255.255.0
255.255.255.0
```

but expected was:

```
Some IP: 10.0.0.0
Some IP: 255.255.255.0
10.0.0.0
```

Comment: for clarity, please provide complete output.

Comment: why are you even trying to do function programing in C++? the power of the language comes by being multi-paradigm..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the manual:

> The inet_ntoa() function converts the Internet host address in, given
>   in network byte order, to a string in IPv4 dotted-decimal notation.
>   The string is returned in a statically allocated buffer, which
>   subsequent calls will overwrite.

Both `net` and `mask` will point to the same buffer, and, of course, the buffer will contain the result of the last call.

Comment: Wow I'm a fool. Thank you.